# Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8545

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, web3j

When I am doing one transaction with the help of Java web3j library, it's not connecting to localhost(my private network). And giving this error.

```
package com.kaushik.blockchain;


import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials;
import org.web3j.crypto.WalletUtils;
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.TransactionReceipt;
import org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService;
import org.web3j.tx.Transfer;
import org.web3j.utils.Convert;

public class Application {

    private static final Logger log =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Application().run();
    }
    public void run() throws Exception{
        Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService());
        log.info("Connected to Ethereum client version: "
                + web3j.web3ClientVersion().send().getWeb3ClientVersion());
        Credentials credentials =
                WalletUtils.loadCredentials(
                        "tcs@12345",
                        "D:\\Blockchain_Tech\\node1\\keystore\\UTC--2018-08-10T06-42-22.453383600Z--48B0DDEF3528A1956CF388F61E301C5F20F38DDE");
        log.info("Credentials loaded");
        log.info("Sending Ether ..");
        TransactionReceipt transferReceipt = Transfer.sendFunds(
                web3j, credentials,
                "0x58ef18d5667552b4c0524b9a78cbf9493d2bd74a",  // you can put any address here
                BigDecimal.valueOf(1000), Convert.Unit.ETHER)  // 1 wei = 10^-18 Ether
                .sendAsync().get();
        log.info("Transaction complete : "
                + transferReceipt.getTransactionHash());
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8545
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:225)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:149)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService.performIO(HttpService.java:104)
    at org.web3j.protocol.Service.send(Service.java:31)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.Request.send(Request.java:71)
    at com.saurabh.blockchain.Application.run(Application.java:26)
    at com.saurabh.blockchain.Application.main(Application.java:21)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:124)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:223)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your node's RPC port is 8585 from where you are trying to transfer money(or deploying contract).